# Where to find Android patches?

Tags: android, android-source, android-kernel

I have vanilla linux kernel version 2.6.27. I want to apply android specific patches and convert it to android linux kernel 2.6.27. Where can a user find the patches to convert a normal vanilla kernel into android kernel?

Answer (score 0):

The Android git repos might have what you want here: [https://android.googlesource.com/](https://android.googlesource.com)

Alternatively, I advise you check http://developer.android.com and look at the SDK for clues. Does this help?